# disable touchpad when using mouse

Tags: touchpad

I want to automatically disable my touchpad when I use a mouse. I have tried touchpad indicator which didn't work (error message, couldn't install) and configuration using synaptics driver but it's too complicated for me :(

Any ideas?

Another thing, if I don't use a mouse I would like to configure the touchpad settings, because "disable touchpad while typing" doesn't help and it is really impossible to type right now.

Is there any easy way to change the settings for the touchpad?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install synaptiks (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/kde-config-touchpad/).

It has a nice GUI for what you want.
I guess the actual options shown may differ based on the model of the trackpad, but you should see the "Automatically switch off touchpad, if a mouse is plugged" option.

Also, you may be able to control the delay after which touchpad activates after typing

Comment: Actually it wasn't working but now I know why - there is are more "mouses" listed than there actually are and you have to check the "ignore" button for the one which is not actually a mouse.

Comment: Package `kde-config-touchpad` can not be installed alone :( . And `gpointing-device-settings` auto-disable setting does not work for me (gets unticked).

Comment: not available for 14.04 LTS